# Node Microservices Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, microservices

I have 5 node microservices. The login and signup of my server is controlled by a microservice called  *test-admin* .After Login my *test-admin* gives a token . which I  send as bearer token for authentication for other activities  in *test-admin* server .

now the problem is how should I use the middleware to convert the JWT token to its data in other 4 servers than *test-admin* . should I need 5 middleware in 5 servers . What is the proper method

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities

1. Your test admin is the first entry point of your micro service architecture, so when a request comes in, the test-admin replace the token with the user data and pass it with the request to the other services for processing, kind of a reverse proxy mechanism (be careful to never leak the user data outside of your secure infrastructure)
2. Each of your service calls test-admin with the token when they need the user data

I wouldn't put the code of turning the token into the user data in each microservices as it breaks the single responsability principle.

Comment: i heard about an event bus setup  just before .  should i setup an event bus and let the event bus converts token to its value and its  value is used directly to communicate between the testadmin and other servers . But is it is safe to directly send the details from one server to another server

Comment: That's solution number one, it's safe if the servers are comunnicating between each other in a secure way. What I mean, no access to the server from the outside of the infrastrure, you can't ssh to one of the servers).
Basically, if you put your server in a closed clusters with controlled entry points it is secure. But again you have to be extra careful on your ops and dev.

The second solution will make your servers doing a lot of requests to the test admin but is probably easier to secure

Answer (score 1):

The preceding is a reasonable approach, but it bucks the current trend towards zero trust.

If you have 5 micro-services, you probably have some code that you want to share amongst them.  Decoding the token is just one example.

If they all live together in a monorepo then this would be trivial. Just have all the shared code reside in a module that each micro service imports.

If you your micro services live in separate repos, then consider sharing your code as a private npm package or an npm import from a common code git repo.

In any case, if the other services are only exposed to test-admin, then there's no harm in passing the decoded user data around instead of the token.

Comment: i heard about an event bus setup just before . should i setup an event bus and let the event bus converts token to its value and its value is used directly to communicate between the testadmin and other servers . But is it is safe to directly send the details from one server to another server

Comment: It means sharing the private key between every servers (I add this for @NaveenRavi)